# ¿Por que no puedo obtener la fecha actual en un "DateTimePicker"? plugin de eonasdan

Tags: jquery, datetime

El enlace al `datetimepicker` que utilizo esta [aquí](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Quiero obtener la fecha que indico, pero al hacer clic en un botón externo a el me indica la fecha anterior, no la ultima fecha que indique.

Ej: si indico la fecha `25/07/2017` este me indica la fecha antes seleccionada (`06/02/2017` fecha de hoy, de la publicación) como podría obtener la ultima fecha que indico en ese `input`.

```js
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        icons: {
            time: "fa fa-clock-o",
            date: "fa fa-calendar",
            up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
            down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
        },
        //defaultDate: new Date(),
        minDate: new Date(),
        disabledHours: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        enabledHours: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    });
 $('#crear_fecha').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date());

$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
   alert($('#crear_fecha').data('DateTimePicker').date()._i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/es-do.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<input type='text' class="form-control datetimepicker" name='crear_fecha' id='crear_fecha' />
                            <button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
                                <span class="fa fa-plus"></span><span class="hidden-xs"> Agregar</span>
                            </button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**NOTA:** el calendario no se por un error de la web, pero si deslizan el scroll del navegador lo visualizaran de bajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio todo parece apuntar a que es problema del `.date()._i` que estás usando en el objeto devuelto por `$('#crear_fecha').data('DateTimePicker')`.

He corregido el error de javascript provocado por un mal diseño y he usado directamente el valor devuelto por la llamada `.date()`.

```js
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
  icons: {
    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
    date: "fa fa-calendar",
    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
  },
  minDate: new Date(),
  disabledHours:
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
  enabledHours:
    [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
});
$('#crear_fecha').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(new Date());

$(document).on('click', '#Crear', function() {
  alert($('#crear_fecha').data('DateTimePicker').date());
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/locale/es-do.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.45/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <input type='text' class="datetimepicker" name='crear_fecha' id='crear_fecha' />
      <button type="button" id="Crear" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
        <span class="hidden-xs">Agregar</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Tras eso el control funciona como se espera.

Comment: gracias hermano por la solución y por la rapidez. mil gracias.

Comment: De nada, fue un placer :)